# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, nullpointerexception, adapter

Entiendo que esta pregunta puede estar duplicada, pero no encontré una solución.

Para poner en contexto tengo una Activity principal,un adapter y una clase con getter & setters. Desde la clase principal obtengo un dato desde Firebase y lo asigno con un set a un titulo que luego llamo desde el adapter. Hasta ahí todo bien, el codigo funciona correctamente, pero cuando llamo el bloque mencionado anteriormente a través de un onclick por segunda vez la app se crashea tirándome el siguiente error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.pppp.onex.InfoWindowData.getTitle()' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at com.example.pppp.onex.CustomInfoWindowAdapter.getInfoContents(CustomInfoWindowAdapter.java:49)
```

Les dejo el codigo de las clases mencionadas anteriormente:

**MapsActivity.java**

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

                db.collection("marcadores")
                        .get()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    for (final QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {


                                        Log.d(TAG,String.valueOf(marker.getPosition().latitude));

                                        if(String.valueOf(marker.getPosition().latitude).equals(String.valueOf(document.getData().get("latitude"))) && String.valueOf(marker.getPosition().longitude).equals(String.valueOf(document.getData().get("longitude")))){

                                            InfoWindowData info = new InfoWindowData();

                                            info.setTitle(marker.getId());
                                            CustomInfoWindowAdapter customInfoWindow = new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(MapsActivity.this);
                                            mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(customInfoWindow);

                                            marker.setTag(info);
                                            marker.showInfoWindow();

                                            break;
                                        }

                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                                }
                            }
                        });

                return false;
            }
        });
```

**CustomInfoWindowAdapter.java**

```
public CustomInfoWindowAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(final Marker m) {
        //Carga layout personalizado.
        //View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.infowindow_layout, null);
        View v = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.infowindow_layout, null);
        InfoWindowData infoWindowData = (InfoWindowData) m.getTag();
            TextView title = ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.infoWindowAdapterTextView));
                title.setText(infoWindowData.getTitle());
        return v;
    }
```

**InfoWindowData.java**

```
public class InfoWindowData {
    private String title;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```

**Desde ya muchas gracias!**

Comment: hace 2 días tuve un problema igual a ese error y se debió a que no tenia en mi xml asignada la id a la que hacia referencia en mi archivo java.

Comment: @Artudoxo Lo tengo asi:  `android:id="@+id/infoWindowAdapterTextView"`, asi que creo que eso no es el problema.

Comment: Es que el mismo error dice que a lo que estas tratando de llamar no tiene un objeto de referencia, también por eso te digo, no esta cogiendo la variable title que hiciste en InfoWindowsData.java, 'java.lang.String com.example.pppp.onex.InfoWindowData.getTitle()' on a null object reference

Comment: Eso lo entiendo, pero no encuentro una solución, trate de todo pero no encuentro como solucionarlo en el codigo

Comment: @TaD el valor de InfoWindowData es null en CustomInfoWindowAdapter, te sugiero agregar el valor de info el cual tiene el titulo al instanciar CustomInfoWindowAdapter , revisa mi respuesta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te sugiero modifiques la clase `CustomInfoWindowAdapter`, agregando en el constructor el valor que instancias de `infoWindowData`, el cual tiene el valor del titulo, de esta forma no obtendrás un valor null.

```
   private InfoWindowData infoWindowData;

   public CustomInfoWindowAdapter(Context context, InfoWindowData infoWindowData ){
            this.context = context;
            this.infoWindowData  = infoWindowData;
        }
        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(final Marker m) {
            //Carga layout personalizado.
            //View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.infowindow_layout, null);
            View v = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater()
                    .inflate(R.layout.infowindow_layout, null);
            //InfoWindowData infoWindowData = (InfoWindowData) m.getTag();
                TextView title = ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.infoWindowAdapterTextView));
                    title.setText(infoWindowData.getTitle());
            return v;
        }
```

desde tu clase `MapsActivity` cuando instancies `CustomInfoWindowAdapter` envía el valor de `info` que tiene un valor asignado para el titulo:

```
 ...
 ...
 InfoWindowData info = new InfoWindowData();
 info.setTitle(marker.getId());
CustomInfoWindowAdapter customInfoWindow = new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(MapsActivity.this, info); //Envia el valor de info.
 ...
 ...
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta, muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Me da gusto pude ayudarte , saludos @TaD