# Devolucion de valores nulos en Kotlin - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, poo, kotlin

Estoy iniciando con la programación en Kotlin - Android Studio.
Tengo la siguiente clase **Ciudad** con las siguiente estructura:

```js
package com.example.practica_android;

public class Ciudad {

    public int id;
    public String nombre;

    public Ciudad(int id, String nombre){
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

}
```

Y estoy tratando de convertir con **JSONObject()** una cadena String como muestro en la siguiente linea de codigo:

```js
package com.example.practica_android

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_first.*
import org.json.JSONException
import org.json.JSONObject

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass as the default destination in the navigation.
 */
class FirstFragment<int> : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        var button_first:Button = view.findViewById(R.id.button_first)

        val json = "{\n" +
                            "\"id\": \"1\",\n" +
                            "\"nombre\": \"MexicoCity\",\n" +
                            "}";

        var ciudad: Ciudad? = null

        try {
            val myjson = JSONObject(json)
            val id: Int =  myjson.getInt("id")
            val nombre:String = myjson.getString("nombre")

            ciudad = Ciudad(id, nombre)

        }catch (e: JSONException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        button_first.setOnClickListener {
            if (ciudad != null) {
                Toast.makeText(this.context, "${ciudad.getId()} - ${ciudad.getNombre()}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this.context, "Los valores son nulos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }

    }
}
```

El detalle es que cuando ejecuto la aplicación el toast solo me muestra que **ciudad.getId()** y **ciudad.getNombre()** son **null**.
Si alguien me podría explicar porque me retorna valores nulos porque estoy creando con normalidad el objeto **Ciudad** y enviando los parámetros. Le agradecería de antemano.

Comment: Si vas a usar Kotlin, tu clase *Ciudad* la puedes hacer data class y quitarles los getter y setters. Esos nos necesarios en Kotlin

Answer (score 0):

Para estos casos de POO debes retornar tus valores como `this.nombre` y `this.id`, ya que estás regresando los datos de la clase

Comment: Me envia este error: **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.example.practica_android.Ciudad.getId()' on a null object reference**

Comment: Me parece que el error es que el objeto no se esta instanciando correctamente [Revisa esta solucion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/280743/java-lang-nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-on-a-null-objec)

Comment: revise una y otra vez y me sigue saliendo el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente cambia tu clase Ciudad a Kotlin y hazla como una `data class`

```
data class Ciudad(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
)
```

Cuando uses Kotlin (para tus modelos) de preferencia que sean de esta manera porque nos evita tener que usar getters y setters. Además automáticamente se implementan otras funciones que puedes usar. Lee un poco sobre [Data classes Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html)

Finalmente te quedaría tal cual lo tienes ya creado

```
val json = "{\n" +
            "\"id\": \"1\",\n" +
            "\"nombre\": \"MexicoCity\",\n" +
            "}";
    val ciudad = JSONObject(json)
    val id: Int =  ciudad.getInt("id")
    val nombre:String = ciudad.getString("nombre")
    print("ciudad id: $id nombre: $nombre")
```

Te recomendaría que no uses JSONObject para parsear tus jsons, pero si tu proyecto es pequeño y ves que no se necesita integrar alguna librería, usar JSONObject esta bien.

Algunas librerías que puedes usar: Kotlin serializer, Gson, Jackson, etc.